# Can't get my UIButton in TableViewCell to fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a subclassed UITableViewCell with a "Start" and "Done" button on each cell.  The "Done" button gets created after you press "Start". If I have my button press logic in my subclassed UITableViewCell file, it triggers just fine.

But I realize I actually want the button press to trigger the editing mode in the table view, so I want to have some logic in my cellForRowAtIndexPath instead of the subclassed file.  But then I can't get the button to fire :(

What am I doing wrong or not understanding?

My TableViewCell.m

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self.startButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250 + 0.60 * self.screenWidth, 65, 150, 30)];
    [self.startButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onStartButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.startButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.16 green:0.65 blue:0.19 alpha:1.0];
    btnLayer = [self.startButton layer];
    [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [self.startButton setTag:1];
    [self addSubview:self.startButton];
}

- (void)onStartButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.countdown)
    {
        [self beginDoneButton];
    }
}
-(void)beginDoneButton {        
    self.startButton.enabled = NO;
    self.startButton.hidden = YES;
    self.doneButton =  [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250 + 0.60 * self.screenWidth, 65, 150, 30)];
    self.doneButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.16 green:0.65 blue:0.19 alpha:1.0];
    CALayer *btnLayer = [self.doneButton layer];
    [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [self.doneButton setTitle:@"Done "forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:self.doneButton];
}
```

My TableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // get index of Data
    int index = (int) indexPath.row;
    id order = [orders objectAtIndex:index];

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"orderCell"];

    cell = [[OrderTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:@"orderCell"];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.customerNameLabel.text = [order objectForKey:@"first_name"];
    cell.orderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Order #%@",     [order objectForKey:@"order_id"]];
    [cell.customerImageView  sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:    [order objectForKey:@"profile_image"]]
              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stub"]
 ];
    [cell.messageButton setTitle:@"Message" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// This doesn't work
    [cell.doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onDoneButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;
}

// This doesn't get fired
- (IBAction)onDoneButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"pressed");
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
    NSIndexPath *pathToCell = [self.tv indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

Comment: What's wrong is that cell.doneButton is nil when you try to add its target and action, since that button is not created until you click the start button.

Comment: @rdelmar thanks. you're right, do you have a suggestion for how i might resolve this?

Comment: Create doneButton in initWithStyle: reuseIdentifier then set doneButton.hidden = 1. When you click startButton unhide it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

In your custom table view cell, create your buttons but don't add target/actions to them Just connect them to an IBOutlet in your cell's class.

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, cast your cell pointer to your custom cell class, and use cell.button1Outlet outlet to set the target/action on the buttons with the view controller as the target. Now your cell buttons will invoke a method in the view controller, not in the cell, even though the outlets belong to the cells.